# Fibonacci coding by the Zeckendorf's theorem

Tags: c, algorithm, output

There is a code that interpret x to a fibonacci coding by the zeckendorf's theorem. The problem is that the code works **NOT** for all input values.

**Example**:

*Input* -> *Output*

**3** -> **100**

**4** -> **101**

**7** -> **1010**

**100** -> **1000010100**

Nevertheless, when I input the value  **34639092**, output is **101000010100101000000000100010011010**, which is the wrong answer (zeckendorf's theorem).

The right answer is **101000010100101000000000100010010010**, they are almost similar, but there is no **"1"** in the 4 position on the right. When debugging the code, you can see that this **"1"** mustn't appear in the wrong answer.

I can't understand reason of output the wrong answer. I suspect an error in the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long count = -1;
    unsigned long a, b, k, x, supercount = 0,  sumc = 0;
    a = 0;
    b = 1;
    scanf ("%lu", &x);
    k = x;
    if (x == 0){
        printf("0");
    }
    for(;x > 0;){
        while ((k >= 0) && (a <= x-b)){
            a = a + b;
            b = a - b;
            k -= 1;
            count ++;
        }
        x -= a;
        sumc |= 1 << (count-1);
        b = 1;
        a = 0;
        count = -1;
    }
    unsigned long r = sumc;
    while (r != 0){
        r /= 2;
        supercount++;
    }
    int arr[supercount];
    for (int q = 0; q < supercount; q ++){
        if (sumc !=0 ){
            arr[q] = sumc % 2;
            sumc /= 2;
        }
    }
    for (int i = supercount-1; i >=0 ; i--){
        printf ("%d", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help to explain that in the loop, a and b are Fibonacci numbers, for i = 0 to ..., a = fib(i), b = fib(i-1). The binary encoding least significant bit is equivalent to fib(2) == 1 (fib(0) and fib(1)) aren't used. So 3 = 100 = fib(4) and 4 = 101 = fib(4) + fib(2).

Comment: Most probably, your  `sumc` is overflowing.(it only has 32bits)

Comment: @wildplasser, 64.

Comment: You are coding on a DEC Alpha? Cool!

Comment: @wildplasser: Use Windows much?  Most modern Unix systems have 64-bit `long`.

Comment: This code is massively overcomplicated.  Try rewriting it without `k`, `arr`, and `supercount` and see if the bug goes away.  (You can do without `sumc` and even `count` if you’re clever.)

Comment: @DavisHerring this isn't the cause of problem.

Comment: @hOUSTANSTARxyolo - just a comment here. I'm wondering if the array of bits should include fib(1) == 1 (not used) and fib(0) == 0 (used only if x = 0). So the results would be Z(0) = 1, Z(3) = 10000,  Z(4) = 10100, Z(100) = 100001010000 (fib(11) + fib(6) + fib(4)), ... .

Comment: @rcgldr my algorithm is right. but i just realized that circular shift  is not a good decision here. using massive better.

Comment: @rcgldr but ur answer were beautiful until test that input 43966558511403 :)

Comment: @hOUSTANSTARxyolo - I'm not sure what you mean, but I tested 43966558511403 and it appears to be correct. I also tested other values such as 18446744073709551615 (2^64-1).

Comment: @rcgldr the right answer is 10101001010101000100101010010001010010100100000100010000000100000.

Comment: @hOUSTANSTARxyolo - I updated my answer to include a check of the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be here:

```
        sumc |= 1 << (count-1);
```

assuming that unsigned long casts to 64 bits on your compiler, it should be:

```
        sumc |= (unsigned long)1 << (count-1);
```

Alternate version that just stores 1 bits into arr. Minor changes to work with Visual Studio.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;
int main()
{
    int arr[96] = {0};  /* fib(93) is max fib() <= 2^64 */
    int count;
    uint64_t a, b, x, y, z;
    scanf("%llu", &x);  /* llu needed for 64 bit input for VS */
    if (x == 0){
        printf("0\n");
        return 0;
    }
    y = x;          /* save x */
    while(x != 0){
        count = 0;  /* count == 0 => fib(2) */
        a = 1;      /* fib(2) == fib(count+2) */
        b = 1;      /* fib(1) == fib(count+1) */
        /* find largest fib(count+2) < x */
        while (a <= x-b){
            count++;    /* count += 1 */
            a = a + b;  /* a = fib(count+2) */
            b = a - b;  /* b = fib(count+1) */
        }
        x -= a;     /* subtract fib(count+2) from x */
        arr[count] = 1;
    }
    count = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    while(arr[--count] == 0);
    while(count >= 0){
        printf ("%d", arr[count]);
        count--;
    }
    printf("\n");
    /* check result */
    z = 0;
    a = 1;      /* fib(1) */
    b = 0;      /* fib(0) */
    for(count = 0; count < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); count++){
        a = a + b;  /* a = fib(count+2) */
        b = a - b;  /* b = fib(count+1) */
        if(arr[count] != 0)
            z += a;
    }
    if(y != z)
        printf("mistmatch\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This version is faster, since it only uses one loop to find all the Fibonacci terms that sum up to x.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;
int main()
{
    int arr[96] = {0};  /* fib(93) is max fib() <= 2^64 */
    int count;
    uint64_t a, b, x, y, z;
    /* these could be calculated with a one time loop */
    a = 12200160415121876738ull;    /* fib(93) */
    b = 7540113804746346429ull;     /* fib(92) */
    count = 93-2;                   /* not using fib(1) or fib(0) */
    scanf("%llu", &x);  /* llu needed for 64 bit input for VS */
    if (x == 0){
        printf("0\n");
        return 0;
    }
    y = x;          /* save x */
    while(x != 0){                  /* main loop */
        if(x >= a){                 /* if x >= fib(count+2) */
            x -= a;                 /*  update x and arr */
            arr[count] = 1;
        }
        count--;
        b = a - b;                  /* b = fib(count+1) */
        a = a - b;                  /* a = fib(count+2) */
    }
    count = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    while(arr[--count] == 0);
    while(count >= 0){
        printf ("%d", arr[count]);
        count--;
    }
    printf("\n");
    /* check result */
    z = 0;
    a = 1;      /* fib(1) */
    b = 0;      /* fib(0) */
    for(count = 0; count < sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); count++){
        a = a + b;  /* a = fib(count+2) */
        b = a - b;  /* b = fib(count+1) */
        if(arr[count] != 0)
            z += a;
    }
    if(y != z)
        printf("mistmatch\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sumc |= 1ul << (count-1);` would be the shorthand notation.

Comment: @wildplasser - I wasn't sure if all C compilers would have the `ul` suffix. In the case of Visual Studio, 64 bit integers are `unsigned long long`, the suffix is `ull`, and scanf() needs "%llu" .

Comment: @hOUSTANSTARxyolo - I updated my answer to include a second example that starts off with fib(93), and does a single loop looking for the Fibonacci terms that sum up to x.